# C language variable in executable file

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, exe, compiler-optimization

Simply coding  C file like bellow:

```
int main()
{
    int a = 999;
    return 0;
}
```

after compile and link using gcc, it will generate a executable file (e.g. .exe, .out)

But when I open (NOT RUNNING) the executable file with some Editor, I can not find the value of variable 'a' the number 999 which in hex is 0x3E7.

My question is:

- Is the variable number 999 exist in executable file?
- If not, where does the variable number stored? How the executable file get the variable number in running?

P.S: I have a little knowledge about memory section like .data .bss .text .etc and assembly language. Evenly I can not find it using ollydbg.

Comment: Did you compile with optimizations on?

Comment: @Michael Petch I use gcc -O1 a.c

Comment: That would be why. With optimizations (even with `-O1`) on the compiler has determined that since you created a variable that is never used that it can remove it entirely. Try building without optimizations (`-O0`).

Comment: If I were you I would compile C code to assembly (option `-S`). Then I would look at the assembler file produced by gcc.

Comment: If ever stored in the executable file, would not be 0xE7 0x03 in that sequence on little-endian ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the important functions of optimization is removing unused stuff.  The behaviour of the program doesn't depend at all on the `999`, and `a` isn't `volatile`, so the assignment isn't part of any visible side-effect, and the program is exactly equivalent to `int main(){return 0;}`

It's a lot easier to look at compiler output in asm form.

On the Godbolt compiler explorer, you can set it up so you can see asm output for `gcc -O0` and `gcc -O1` at the same time, in different panes.  https://godbolt.org/z/wNHEnN.

`mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], 999` is there at `-O0`, along with stack-frame setup fluff.  So the `-O0` output will have `999` as a dword immediate operand to a `mov` instruction.  The variable is local, so you won't find a symbol-table entry for it in the `.data` or `.rdata` sections (like you would with a global with a static initializer).

See also [How to remove "noise" from GCC/clang assembly output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38552116/how-to-remove-noise-from-gcc-clang-assembly-output/38552509#38552509) for more about looking at compiler output.

Answer (score 5):

There is no reason for the compiler to put the value `999` anywhere since it is not used anywhere. The program has the same observable behaviour regardless `999` being somewhere in memory or not.

ISO/IEC 9899:TC2 - 5.1.2.3 Program execution:

> 3. In the abstract machine, all expressions are evaluated as specified by the semantics. **An actual implementation need not evaluate part of an expression if it can deduce that its value is not used and that no needed side effects are produced** (including any caused by calling a function or accessing a volatile object).